# querying stripe api & display image

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have been following a tutorial to query Stripe API and display data. One thing that is not mentioned is how to query the images and display it. I can see from the structure that the images property is there but I need some help to display it. I assume it should be the same logic how it is displaying the product name but I just need to understand to follow the same logic for the images.

Here is my query, I have added the image option in my query:
[image]

and can see the result in GrapiQL:
[image]

Here is example of how I am mapping over my products to display correctly. From what I understand I need to do the same for the image. I have followed the same logic by just replacing product with image but just can't seem to get it working. Here is the snippet:

```
const Products = () => {
  return (<StaticQuery query={PRODUCTS_QUERY}
    render={
      ({ allStripeSku, allStripeProduct }) => {

        return allStripeProduct.edges.map(product => {
          const skus = allStripeSku.edges.filter(
            sku => sku.node.product.id === product.node.id
          )
          return (
            <Product
              key={product.node.id}
              skus={skus}
              product={product.node} />
          )
        })
        return
      }
    }
  />)
}
```

Can anyone please point my in the right direction so I can get this working?

Comment: What is the exact problem here?

Comment: Trying to query images and display it. In the example above I am able to query the product names successfully but now trying to do the same with images.

Comment: I mean, what's the error can you show ?

Comment: Not getting any errors just more how do I go about doing this. Not sure if I understand the API correctly. Can query the product name, just need to do the same for the images. Do you have experience with the Stripe API @OzanManav?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 lines of code:

- in GraphQL query to return `images` alongside `id` and `name` as you've already done
- in `ProductCard` component to return an `<img>` element using the query field added above

For me this meant adding the `+` lines below:

- in src/components/Products/Products.js

  - [image: query Stripe for images]
- in src/components/Products/ProductCard.js

  - [image: use Stripe images from query result]

I assume it's the [Gatsby E-commerce Tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/ecommerce-tutorial/) you were following; if so please be aware that, since your OP, they've updated the docs so it [no longer uses the deprecated Orders API](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24883).